# Don't want headers on ToC, Lists, Bibliography and Appendices

Tags: header-footer, lyx, fancyhdr

I'm using the fancy headers, but I dont want any headers on ToC, Lists, Bibliography and  Appendices. If I put this `\thispagestyle{plain}`, it works on the last page, but when it has for example the ToC 3 pages the second page gets an header anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ToC and lists of figures/tables, try adding

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

in an ERT just before the first of these, and

```
\clearpage\pagestyle{fancy}
```

after the last of them. Similar, for appendices/bibliography, add `\pagestyle{plain}` just before them.

`\thispagestyle` affects only the *current* page, whereas `\pagestyle` affects all following pages.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I understand your question right.

you can specify your header and footer with:

```
\fancyhead[C]{}  % even and odd pages center
\fancyhead[OL]{} % odd pages left
\fancyhead[ER]{} % even pages right
\fancyhead[OR]{} % odd pages right
\fancyhead[EL]{} % even pages left
```

It could be neccessary to protect the style:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
```